# Finding MSB set of the maximal magnitude element in array

Tags: c, algorithm, math, optimization, arm

Given an array of `len` elements of type `signed short` it is to find a position of the Most Significant Bit set in the maximal absolute value element in the array. For example, if array L contains `{-134, 123, 0, -890}` then `f(L)` should return `floor(log2(abs(-890)))+1`.

Here is my current function:

```
short MSBSetMaxMagnitude(const short *p, int len)
{
   unsigned int t = 0;

   while (len > 0)
   {
      t |= abs(*p);
      p++;
      len--;
   }
   if(t)
      return (short)(32 - __builtin_clz(t));
   else
      return 0;
}
```

However, it is a bit slow because of the abs() function requiring branching. I've tried to use an abs() without branching instead but it is even slower because it contains at least 3 arithmetical instructions. So I hope that maybe there is an efficient algorithm to find exactly what I need.

Comment: @LMGTFY as I said in the question - this method is slower than abs() from stdlib

Comment: You didn't state which branchless version you tried :)

Comment: @larsman    __inline__ myabs {unsigned int r; int const mask = x >> sizeof(int) * 8 - 1; return  r = (x + mask) ^ mask;} but this is irrelevant to the question. I am not looking for an abs(), but rather for an algorithm which avoids it at all.

Comment: Does this code do what it's supposed to? It will give log2(1) = 1, which doesn't seem right.

Comment: @AndreasBrinck thank you! I call it log2, but I really mean a position of the Most Significant Bit set in the maximal magnitude element in array. So, it should be ceil(log2(abs(maxElem(L))))

Comment: Actually I think you want floor(log2(...) + 1)

Comment: @AndreasBrinck right! Yes, I need floor(log2(...)+1) :)

Comment: Do you have to use an array as input or you can switch to another data structure?

Comment: @icepack array only as input

Comment: Would you use some kind of SIMD instructions (MMX, SSE, Neon etc)?

Comment: @MBo no, thanks! I am on the ARM (w/o NEON and w/o VFP).

Comment: Not even ARMv6 SIMD? http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0491c/CJAHHJHC.html

Comment: @auselen no, it is Arm v5 w/o FP unit

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that you work on the ARM platform, you can use the following implementation of `abs` in 2 instructions:

```
EORS r1, r1, r1, ASR #32 (x = x ^ (x >> 32); carry_flag = sign_bit)
ADC r1, r1, #0           (add the sign_bit to x)
```

If you can tolerate an error of +/-1 in calculations, drop the second instruction; then, you can express it in C:

```
int abs_almost_exact(int x)
{
    return x ^ (x >> 32);
}
```

But the bigger problem is, however, the loop. You will probably benefit much from unrolling (since there is so little to do for each iteration):

```
do { // assuming len is even!
    int value1 = *p++;
    int value2 = *p++;
    value1 = abs(value1); // or replace abs by the hand-made version
    value2 = abs(value2);
    t |= value1;
    t |= value2;
    len--;
}
while (len > 0);
```

Note: I replaced `while {}` by `do {} while` because the compiler i used (ARM compiler) generates better code this way.

Please also note that ARM has latency of 2 clock cycles when loading `short` variables from memory (on the processor i worked with). So, the minimum unrolling factor is 3 (but you should unroll as much as possible anyway).

Oh, and does your processor support reading `short` (half-word) variables from memory at all? I have heard of some very old processors that can't do that. If this is the case for you, you should change the code to load 2 values (1 word) at once, and use some bit-fiddling to separate them.

Comment: Do you know how many clock cycles require a multiplication operation on ARM v5? I have an idea that maybe to use a multiplication to find the square (1 operation) in the loop; but in that case I have to do some calculations after the loop. Still not sure.

Comment: Multiplication of 2 `signed short` variables takes 1 cycle. But you surely aren't planning to calculate square root right afterwards?! If you don't need the exact value, the approximation with the right-shift by 32 is very good (probably the best, because it takes just 1 cycle).

Comment: The task is only: given a MSB set of a square how to find a MSB set of its square root? (of course, after the main loop).

Answer (score 0):

Three arithmetic instructions should take very little time on any modern processor. You are doing two arithmetic operations and a conditional branch in managing the loop and indexing. It is possible that the slowness is due to a combination of data cache misses and a loop that may be difficult for the compiler to unroll due to pointer use and pointer arithmetic.

There is no way to find a value that depends on every element in the array without looking at every element in the array, so the objective should be to make sure the whole thing runs in the time it takes to scan the array.

You can test whether this is the issue by replacing:

```
t |= abs(*p);
```

with
    t |= *p;

If that is not substantially faster, I suggest experimenting with the non-branching abs version in a manually unrolled loop.